Handling A constructor where one of it's properties is gotten from an asynchronous function
So I made this js file and exported my Completion function so I can call this from any file I need it instead of re-coding everything.
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI();

async function Completion(context, prompt) {
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [
      { role: "system", content: context },
      { role: "user", content: prompt }
    ],
    model: "gpt-4-turbo-preview",
  });
  return completion.choices[0].message.content;
}

export default Completion;

So in a separate file, I made some class Car and tried to generate 3 fun facts about the car and the code works but it looks like every time I make an object it has to be in an async function.
import Completion from "./OpenAI.mjs";

class Car {
    constructor(name, year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.about = null;

        (this.initializeAbout = async () => this.about = await this.generateAbout(this.name, this.year))();
    }

    async generateAbout(name, year) {
        const context = "You are a car expert";
        const prompt = `In 3 lines give me 3 fun facts about the car ${name} ${year}`;
        return await Completion(context, prompt);
    }
}

async function main() {
    let merc = new Car("Mercedes GLE", 2022);

    // Wait for the about property to be set

    console.log(merc.name);

    await merc.initializeAbout();
    console.log(merc.about);
}

main();

Is there a better way of going about this? (I'm not experienced with JavaScript)
Thank you!
